# Non-specific error from truffle debugger

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-debugging

I am testing a contract which is using `ecrecover` function of solidity. While its testing when i go with a failed test case while debugging, it doesn't go step by step and at the end return the same error as below. What is the reason of all this?

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
>       at Debugger.step (/home/aniket/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:322984:59)
>       at Object.interpreter (/home/aniket/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:318096:22)
>       at ReplManager.interpret (/home/aniket/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.3/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:203345:18)
>       at bound (domain.js:301:14)
>       at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:314:12)
>       at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:442:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at REPLServer.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:282:10)
>       at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:631:8)

Answer (score 0):

As of a little while ago, truffle debugger was not finished and throwed a lot like this. [Here](http://truffleframework.com/blog/announcing-full-portable-solidity-debugger) says that the debugger is completed now, but i haven't tried it out again yet.